# Create table dynamically in JavaScript with map function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a table dynamically in JavaScript using a map function but getting the error. Could anyone please give pointer?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Here is my code:

```js
// List of movies
let movies = [
    {
        title: "Fight Club",
        rank: 10,
        id: "tt0137523"
    },
    {
        title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
        rank: 1,
        id: "tt0111161"
    }
    
]


function displayMovies(movies){
   let table = '<table>';
   table += `<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Rank</th></tr>`;
   movies.map((movie, index) => ({
       table = table + `<tr>`,
       table = table + `<td>` + `Title:` `${movie.id}` + `</td>`,
       table = table + `<td>` + `Title:` `${movie.title}` + `</td>`,
       table = table + `<td>` + `Title:` `${movie.rank}` + `</td>`
    }));  
    table += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("movies-list").innerHTML = table;
}

displayMovies(movies);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
    <div id="movies-list">
      <!-- The div element where the movies table will be inserted --> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace `=> ({` with `=> {`.on your line with `map` in it.  If you use `({ ...})` it thinks you want to return an object.

Comment: and also change the `.map()` to a `.forEach()` (although it will still work with map, forEach is the way to go if you're not using the return value of `.map`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to use `Array.forEach` instead of `Array.map` on `displayMovies` function.
   `Array.map` is used to creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. There is no need to return a new array based on `movies` array so it's better to use `Array.forEach`.
2. Wrong syntax when adding `td` values inside loop.

```
table = table + `<td>` + `Title:` `${movie.id}` + `</td>`,
```

should be replaced with

```
table = table + `<td>Title: ${movie.id}</td>`;
```

So remove ',' on last and use operator between `Title:`  `${movie.id}` or make it as above.

```js
// List of movies
let movies = [
    {
        title: "Fight Club",
        rank: 10,
        id: "tt0137523"
    },
    {
        title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
        rank: 1,
        id: "tt0111161"
    }  
];

function displayMovies(movies){
   let table = '<table border="1">';
   table += `<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Rank</th></tr>`;
   movies.forEach((movie, index) => {
       table = table + `<tr>`;
       table = table + `<td>Title: ${movie.id}</td>`;
       table = table + `<td>Title: ${movie.title}</td>`;
       table = table + `<td>Title: ${movie.rank}</td>`;
       table += `</tr>`;
    });
    table += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("movies-list").innerHTML = table;
}

displayMovies(movies);
```

```html
<div id="movies-list"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I pasted your code in my editor but now I am getting this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Try to change the id name to `movieslist` and try.

Answer (score 1):

### Dynamic example if the display order is fine from the data

I wanted to create something similar in React. Still wanted to add a more dynamic answer here, maybe it may come in handy for some folks.

The script takes the movies and creates head titles and contents from it. The `createHead` function expects a movie object, simply takes the keys, makes every titles first character uppercase and wraps all titles with tr and th's.

The `createRow` function does almost the same for the content part, without the uppercase part and instead of taking the keys it takes the value of each movies object property. This function gets iterated inside the `createTable` function with a map function to store the newly created rows inside a const:

```
const rows = movies.map((movie) => {
  return createRow(movie)
});
```

[CodePen example here](https://codepen.io/tommygunPrrrrat/pen/oNGRrGx?editors=1010)

Same example here inline:

```js
const movies = [
    {
        title: "Fight Club",
        rank: 10,
        id: "tt0137523"
    },
    {
        title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
        rank: 1,
        id: "tt0111161"
    }
];

// Creates the table head entries. Simply gets the first movie and takes the keys as titles
const createHead = (headObject) => {
    let cells = "";
    for (const key in headObject) {
      // This takes the first letter of each title and uppercases it
      cells += `<th>${key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)}</th>`;
    }

    return `<tr>${cells}</tr>`;
};

// Creates the content entries
const createRow = (rowObject) => {
    let cells = "";
    for (const key in rowObject) {
      cells += `<td>${rowObject[key]}</td>`;
    }

    return `<tr>${cells}</tr>`;
};

// Main function to create it all
const createTable = (movies) => {
    const rows = movies.map((movie) => {
      return createRow(movie)
    });
  
    // Creates the table head titles
    const headRow = createHead(movies[0])
    
    // Takes the rows and concats again to prevent some weird commas from appearing?
    let optimizedRows = ''
    rows.forEach((row) => {
      optimizedRows += row;
    });

    // This finally combines table, head and body contents
    const table = (`
      <table>
        <thead>${headRow}</thead>
        <tbody>${optimizedRows}</tbody>
      </div>
    `);

    document.getElementById("movies-list").innerHTML = table;
};

createTable(movies);
```

```html
<div id="movies-list">Loading movies ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors.

In `demo.js` I used single quotes instead of backticks for the string literals that did not require interpolation. You were also missing several `+` operators. Also, in `index.html` I moved the `<script>...</script>` tag below the "movies-list" div.

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    <div id="movies-list">
      <!-- The div element where the movies table will be inserted --> 
    </div>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`demo.js`

```
// List of movies
let movies = [
    {
        title: "Fight Club",
        rank: 10,
        id: "tt0137523"
    },
    {
        title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
        rank: 1,
        id: "tt0111161"
    }
    
]


function displayMovies(movies){
   let table = '<table>';
   table += '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Rank</th></tr>';
   movies.map((movie, index) => {
       table = table + '<tr>',
       table = table + '<td>' + 'Title:' + `${movie.id}` + '</td>',
       table = table + '<td>' + 'Title:' + `${movie.title}` + '</td>',
       table = table + '<td>' + 'Title:' + `${movie.rank}` + '</td>'
    });  
    table += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("movies-list").innerHTML = table;
}

displayMovies(movies);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
    <div id="movies-list">
      <!-- The div element where the movies table will be inserted --> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in `demo.js` you can try this:

```
const movies = [
    {
        title: 'Fight Club',
        rank: 10,
        id: 'tt0137523',
    },
    {
        title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
        rank: 1,
        id: 'tt0111161',
    }
];

const displayMovies = () => {
  let table = '<table border="1">';
  table += '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Rank</th></tr>';
  movies.forEach((movie) => {
    table += `<tr>
                <td>Title: ${movie.id}</td>
                <td>Title: ${movie.title}</td>
                <td>Title: ${movie.rank}</td>
              </tr>`;
  });
  table += '</table>';
  document.getElementById('movies-list').innerHTML = table;
};

displayMovies();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is more readeable

```js
// List of movies
let movies = [
    {
        name: "Fight Club",
        rank: 10,
        id: "tt0137523"
    },
    {
        name: "The Shawshank Redemption",
        rank: 1,
        id: "tt0111161"
    }  
];

function displayTable(){
    let table = '<table border="1">' // Opening Table
    //Header
    table += (`<tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Rank</th>
               </tr>`)

    //Body
    movies.forEach((movie, index) =>{
        table += 
            (`<tr>
                <td>Title: ${movie.id}</td>
                <td>Title: ${movie.name}</td>
                <td>Title: ${movie.rank}</td>
             </tr>`)
    })
    table += '</table>' // Closing Table
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = table;
}


displayTable(movies)
```

```html
<body>

    <main id="main">
        <!-- We gonna display our table here -->
    </main>
     
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```